# Accessing shared DB using iOS and Django

Tags: ios, django

I'm just starting to learn about iOS development, and I figure the best way to get started is to build a simple (but non-trivial) app. My idea is this: have a web interface where a user can create a survey, and then access those surveys through the app and send responses back to the server. The web design part probably won't be terribly difficult -- I've done similar things with Django before. The part that will require learning/effort is the iPhone app.

I've got enough Objective-C that the data structures (model) won't be hard to code, and the UI (view, controller) part shouldn't be bad either. I predict that the interface between web and phone will be difficult, though. In particular, how will I be able to access the database on the server from the phone? I'd like to have a single DB that both web and phone apps use.

What I'd really like to have is a general, broad-strokes description of what I'll need to do to get this all up and running. Am I right in believing that the networking will be the hardest part? Are there any other possible snags? Any advice, or pointers to good resources on the subject, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Networking will probably not be the hardest part here, you're just guessing because that aspect is unfamiliar to you. For example, you can use [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to take care of pretty much all the details of server connection. You can use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert your data to and from a format that is suitable for sending over the wire.

Basically what you might do is:

- Mobile app sends a HTTP GET request to the server for survey info.
- Server responds with a JSON description of the survey.
- User fills out survey.
- When done, the app sends the responses back in JSON format as a HTTP POST to the server.
- Server stores the results in the database.

One of the key points here is that the app on the phone does *not* try to access the database directly. All requests go through your Django web app.